# JNDI lookup for JBoss 7 fails

Tags: jboss, datasource, jndi

Hi,

I've setup a datasource in jboss standalone.xml and trying to access the datasource. The app doesn't start siting errors from my web.xml configurations.

Have been getting this error, no matter the change in settings:

{"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [
    "jboss.naming.context.java.module.myapp.myapp.env.myDataSource is missing [jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.myDataSource]
]}}}

Here is my web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>SQL Server Spring JNDI Datasource </description>
    <!-- res-ref-name>jdbc/myDataSource</res-ref-name-->
    <res-ref-name>myDataSource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>       
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>  
    <lookup-name>java:jboss/datasources/myDataSource</lookup-name>  
</resource-ref>
```

Here is my setting in standalone.xml

```
<datasources>
 <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDataSource" pool-name="myDataSource" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://10.0.0.0:1433;DatabaseName=my_Local</connection-url>
                    <driver>mssql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>user</user-name>
                        <password>user1</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="mssql" module="com.microsoft">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
```

I've copied the SQL server jdbc jar file to $jbosshome/modules/com/microsoft/main
and added a module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.microsoft"><resources>
<resource-root path="sqljdbc4.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
<module name="javax.api"/>
<module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
<module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
-vg

Answer (score 0):

Remote lookup of datasources is not supported in AS7.
[Similar question has been answered here](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/DataSourceConfigurationInAS7?_sscc=t)